# Why Menu Meter and htop report inconsistent occupied memory and total memory?

Tags: memory, process, macbook-pro, top, htop

On my Macbook Pro running OS X 10.10.3, [Menu Meter](http://www.ragingmenace.com/software/menumeters/) and [htop](http://hisham.hm/htop/) seem to be reporting inconsistent memory results:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no one true answer for 'how much memory am I using'. Most tools (including htop) reporting memory usage get their values from /proc/meminfo. They all use a calculation to arrive at 'total memory use'.

For example on one of my VM's:

htop: 3893/7872MB

top: 77183488K used 8061572k total

free -m : used 7537 used total 7872

cat /proc/meminfo:

```
MemTotal:        8061572 kB
MemFree:          354652 kB
Buffers:          340944 kB
Cached:          3377788 kB
SwapCached:        52844 kB
Active:          4473928 kB
Inactive:        2824168 kB
Active(anon):    2647356 kB
Inactive(anon):   932236 kB
Active(file):    1826572 kB
Inactive(file):  1891932 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       2097148 kB
SwapFree:        1986984 kB
Dirty:               516 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       3532084 kB
Mapped:            19120 kB
Shmem:               228 kB
Slab:             320184 kB
SReclaimable:     238652 kB
SUnreclaim:        81532 kB
KernelStack:        1424 kB
PageTables:        18428 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     6127932 kB
Committed_AS:    4140908 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      288792 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359438880 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:   3043328 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       10240 kB
DirectMap2M:     8378368 kB
```

I am not sure what Menu Meters is reporting as 'Memory Pages' but if you post your "cat /proc/meminfo" we should be able to explain.